# IF Statement producing correct 'False' value, #Error when True

Tags: formula, formula-field

Wrestled with this one for a while before deciding to ask the SFDC SE community's help: 
Basically, a formula field on a Child object is looking up a parent Object value

```
IF(( ISNULL(Foo__r.Foo_Views__c) ), 
( Quoted_Rate__c * 1000 / Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c ), 
(( Quoted_Rate__c * 1000)/ Foo__r.Foo_Views__c ) 
)
```

When the Foo_Views__c is **not** Null, the formula correctly calculates the value-- and existing fields that effectively broke this formula into two fields prove this.

However, when the value is Null (and therefore *true*, the value returned is an #Error)

Is there some issue or unspoken rule I keep missing? Thanks!

**Edit**: to confirm, the Foo_Downloads__c field has a value populated for both the records I tested with, and a separate field populates a value just using this formula:
( Quoted_Rate__c * 1000 / Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c )
This field's data type is Currency, and while our instance is only using one currency, could this be causing an issue?

Comment: Is it possible that both Foo__r.Foo_Views__c AND Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c are both empty or a zero value? That might give you a divide-by-zero error, resulting in #Error.

Comment: what do you want to return if Foo_Views__c is not NULL and Foo_Downloads__c is NULL?

Comment: @Andrei.Z I am fine with it Error'ing out then, because from a business-logic standpoint, if neither of those fields is populated, the field should error out. The issue is that the Foo_Downloads__c field is populated with a value, but the formula still errors out.

Comment: You can try the suggested solution. It checks all scenarios and you will sure that value of Foo_Downloads__c field is not null and 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code:

`IF(( ISNULL(Foo__r.Foo_Views__c) ), 
( IF(( AND(NOT(ISNULL(Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c)), Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c > 0) ), Quoted_Rate__c * 1000 / Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c, 0 )), 
(( Quoted_Rate__c * 1000)/ Foo__r.Foo_Views__c ) 
)`

You need to check that `Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c` is not null and its value is greater than 0.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Weird, these are all continuing to error out. Could there be some weird Currency data type getting involved?

Comment: What is the data type of Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c ?

Comment: @Anuarg, it is a Number(14, 0). The Formula field we're trying to build here is a Currency(formula) field.

Comment: You can debug value of Foo__r.Foo_Download__c, if it seems non-numeric value then will think of another solution.

Comment: I have tried this in my org and created a currency formula field that perform operation on number. It executes successfully and value displayed on currency formula field.

Comment: Could you please do one thing. Create a Currency(formula) field on your object and try to inset value on that field when any record created. If it successfully insert value in field then it might be a different scenario.

Comment: sure although I have several read/write currency fields already on the Child object of Foo and on Foo itself, and those values insert fine

Comment: ok this is interesting. I swapped in the a Foo_Format_Type_CPM formula field which is using the (Quoted_Rate__c * 1000 / Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c ) formula and passing the correct value. However, this is also error'ing out. There's something off about the IF statement. Tried googling this, but could you point me to a recommended resource on debugging formula fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40992/discussion-between-anurag-bhardwaj-and-gpp).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please include a null and >0 check for `Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c` before the division is performed.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(( ISNULL(Foo__r.Foo_Views__c) ), 
IF(OR(ISNULL(Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c),Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c==0),
(0),
( Quoted_Rate__c * 1000 / Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c )), 
(( Quoted_Rate__c * 1000)/ Foo__r.Foo_Views__c ) 
)
```

instead of 0 in (0) put any value you want to return when Foo_Downloads__c = null or Foo_Downloads__c = 0

Comment: I tried this as well. Feel like this almost deserves a case being logged to Salesforce support...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your contributions! I ended up realizing that due to the business requirements of this object, the 'downloads' field needed to be added as a local field in the same object that this Formula field in question was in, so I was able to resolve that.

I suspect that the Error came from either an Order of Operations e.g., the Quoted_Rate__c * 1000 / Foo__r.Foo_Downloads__c  statement needed additional parentheses wrapped around the multiplication operation, and because number fields are automatically written as '0' when null, I likely would have been fine using an IF(Foo__r.Foo_Views__c = 0, ...) as well.